# How to use docker ENTRYPOINT with shell script file combine parameter

Tags: bash, shell, docker

I write shell script file and use this with docker ENTRYPOINT
but when I run docker image, it just stops without any error log because of entrypoint code line

my Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
MAINTAINER limtaegeun <imori333@gmail.com>

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y nginx
RUN echo "\ndaemon off;" >> /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

# Define mountable directories.
VOLUME ["/etc/nginx/sites-enabled", "/etc/nginx/certs", "/etc/nginx/conf.d", "/var/log/nginx", "/var/www/html"]

ENV CONTAINER_NAME nodejs
ENV SERVER_NAME myserver.com
ENV PEM_PATH /etc/nginx/certs/cert.pem
ENV KEY_PATH /etc/nginx/certs/cert.key

WORKDIR /etc/nginx

ADD ./sites-available/ssl /etc/nginx/sites-available/ssl
ADD ./docker-entrypoint.sh /etc/nginx/docker-entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod 777 /etc/nginx/docker-entrypoint.sh
EXPOSE 80 443
ENTRYPOINT /etc/nginx/docker-entrypoint.sh ${CONTAINER_NAME} ${SERVER_NAME} ${PEM_PATH} ${KEY_PATH}
CMD ["nginx"]
```

docker-entrypoint.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

CONTAINER_NAME=$1
SERVER_NAME=$2
PEM_PATH=$3
KEY_PATH=$4

rm -f /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default
sed -ri 's@CONTAINER_NAME@'${CONTAINER_NAME}'@' /etc/nginx/sites-available/ssl
sed -ri 's@SERVER_NAME@'${SERVER_NAME}'@' /etc/nginx/sites-available/ssl
sed -ri 's@PEM_PATH@'${PEM_PATH}'@' /etc/nginx/sites-available/ssl
sed -ri 's@KEY_PATH@'${KEY_PATH}'@' /etc/nginx/sites-available/ssl
# cp -f sites-available/ssl sites-available/default
ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/ssl /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default
```

my docker run command

```
docker run -v /home/ubuntu/Docker-nginx-cloudflare-ssl-proxy/certs:/etc/nginx/certs \
--name nginx-ssl -p 443:443 -p 80:80 --network nginx-net --rm -d nginx-cloudfare-ssl-proxy
```

what is the problem??

Answer (score 27, accepted):

When a Docker container is run, it runs the `ENTRYPOINT` (only), passing the `CMD` as command-line parameters, and when the `ENTRYPOINT` completes the container exits.  In the Dockerfile the `ENTRYPOINT` has to be JSON-array syntax for it to be able to see the `CMD` arguments, and the script itself needs to actually run the `CMD`, typically with a line like `exec "$@"`.

The single simplest thing you can do to clean this up is not to try to go back and forth between environment variables and positional parameters.  The `ENTRYPOINT` script will be able to directly read the `ENV` variables you set in the Dockerfile (or override with `docker run -e` options).  So if you delete the first lines of the script that set these variables from positional parameters, and make sure to run the `CMD`

```sh
#!/bin/sh
# delete the lines that set CONTAINER_NAME et al.
rm -f /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default
sed -ri 's@CONTAINER_NAME@'${CONTAINER_NAME}'@' /etc/nginx/sites-available/ssl
...
# and add this at the end
exec "$@"
```

and then change the Dockerfile to not pass positional parameters but do use JSON-array syntax for `ENTRYPOINT`

```sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/etc/nginx/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["nginx"]
```

that should get you off the ground.

It's worth considering how much of this you actually need to be configurable.  For instance, would you ever need a path different from the default `/etc/nginx/certs` inside the isolated container filesystem space?  Usually with the standard [nginx](https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx) Docker Hub image you work with it by injecting an entire complete configuration file and if you choose to do that it simplifies your Docker setup.

Other generic suggestions: remove the `VOLUME` declarations (they potentially cause confusing behavior later in the Dockerfile and leak anonymous volumes and aren't otherwise necessary); don't make executable files world-writable (`chmod 0755`, not `0777`); `RUN apt-get update && apt-get install` in the same Dockerfile command.