# Running a simple Python Container on Ubuntu

Tags: python, docker, image, dockerfile, containers

So I have a directory that just includes a `Dockerfile`. I want to experiment with the poetry package in python. So I do not want any python files to be inside it initially because I want to create a poetry project from scratch inside the directory. So ı went ahead and built the image called `local:python3.10ubuntu` for it. When I ran the container for it with the command `docker run --name py3.10ubuntu local:python3.10ubuntu` I can see that the docker container was not running why is that and how would I be able to run it. when I try to see the docker logs for the container it wouldnt show anything as well. Besides starting the container how would I be able to run the command shell within the container and run python files?

Directory Structure:

```
.
└── Dockerfile
```

Dockerfile contents

```
FROM python:3.10-slim
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir poetry
```

Comment: Do you have a shell script in the repo ? Then you can use entry point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your dockerfile is not configured properly try to refer below website on how to create a docker file for poetry.

[Dockerfile for poetry](https://binx.io/2022/06/13/poetry-docker/)

Also to run a shell script in dockerfile it could be done if your code has a .sh file. You could either use RUN, ENTRYPOINT, CMD or combination of these to run the shell script in your docker file.Refer the below answer

[Using ENTRYPOINT to run shell script in dockerfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60485743/how-to-use-docker-entrypoint-with-shell-script-file-combine-parameter)

To run a docker container you can use

```
docker run -it <docker-image>
```

Try exec command to run something inside the container

```
docker exec -it <container-name-or-id> bash
```

Comment: what does the `it` parameters functionality do. @llinux_beginner gave it as `-ti`.

Comment: `-i` means interactive and `-t` means Allocate a pseudo-TTY when you use them together with `-it` and run a docker command with these flags it will take you inside the docker container . If you run a docker container using `-itd` commands it runs the container in the background `-d` stands for detach. You can get a better understanding from the documentation :https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/

Answer (score 1):

ughhhh?

```
docker run -ti <your_image>
```

or if you want see more than python itself:

```
docker run -ti --entrypoint /bin/bash <your_image>
```